# Putting text on an image

Tags: html, css

I built a simple countdown timer in HTML and now I am looking to put all the text on top of an image. So the image is in the background and the text on top of it.

It's an image of a mac screen and I want text to be inside of the screen if that makes sense :)

Code:

```css
.time-to {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Bangers;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.time-to span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #D9D900;
}

.macPic {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="macPic" class="">
  <img src="Images/mac.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
  <div class='time-to'>
    Slutar Midnatt Söndag :
    <span countdown='' date='December 3, 2017 12:00:00'>&nbsp;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/bo2f1qtr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.time-to {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Bangers;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.time-to span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #D9D900;
}

.macPic {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="macPic" class="">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords_wide.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
  <div class="centered">
    Slutar Midnatt Söndag :
    <span countdown='' date='December 3, 2017 12:00:00'>&nbsp;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to change your image.

Answer (score 1):

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Because the image has a z-index of -1, it will be placed behind the text.

Answer (score 0):

you could use background image, correct me if I misunderstood your question

```
<div class="macPic" class="background-image: url("Images/mac.png");">
          <div class='time-to'>
            Slutar Midnatt Söndag : 
            <span countdown='' date='December 3, 2017 12:00:00'>&nbsp;</span>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS...

```
.time-to{
   position:absolute;
   top:50%;
   left:10%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions:

(1) Set your image as background image for `div class="macPic"`:

```
.macPic {
   background-image:url('Images/mac.png');
}
```

(2) Use positioning as explained [here](https://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/) to let the text float on top of the image:

```
.macPic { position:relative; }
.time-to { position: absolute; }
.img-responsive { position: absolute; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do as follow

```
.macPic {
    position: relative;
}

.time-to {
    position: absolute;
    /* You can replace * with any value that you like */
    top: *px;
    bottom: *px;
    right: *px;
    left: *px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put mac.png image into css folder and add this code to your external file

```
.macPic { background-image:url('Images/mac.png'); }
```